# An error when install cutorch in Torch7 of centos7

Tags: installation, package, torch

I want to install the cutorch and get an error and I don't know how to solve it:

```
(tf0.12.1) [root@sd-bigdata-gpu-02 deepmask]# luarocks install cutorch
Installing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cutorch-scm-1.rockspec...
Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cutorch-scm-1.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode
Cloning into 'cutorch'...
remote: Counting objects: 227, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (180/180), done.
remote: Total 227 (delta 64), reused 91 (delta 45), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (227/227), 234.16 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (64/64), done.
Warning: unmatched variable LUALIB

jopts=$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_CONF)

……

[ 81%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/generated/./THC_generated_THCTensorMaskedDouble.cu.o
Scanning dependencies of target THC
[ 82%] [ 84%] [ 85%] [ 86%] [ 87%] [ 88%] [ 89%] [ 90%] [ 92%] Building CXX object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THCCachingAllocator.cpp.o
Building CXX object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THCCachingHostAllocator.cpp.o
Building C object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THCGeneral.c.o
Building C object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THCStorageCopy.c.o
Building C object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THCTensor.c.o
Building C object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THCTensorCopy.c.o
Building CXX object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THCStream.cpp.o
Building CXX object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THCTensorRandom.cpp.o
Building C object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THCThreadLocal.c.o
In file included from generic/THCTensor.c:1:0,
                 from /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-4055/cutorch/lib/THC/THCGenerateAllTypes.h:17,
                 from /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-4055/cutorch/lib/THC/THCTensor.c:7:
/tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-4055/cutorch/lib/THC/generic/THCTensor.c: In function ‘THCudaByteTensor_newExpand’:
/tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-4055/cutorch/lib/THC/generic/THCTensor.c:304:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘THLongStorage_calculateExpandGeometry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   THLongStorage_calculateExpandGeometry(tensor->size,
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THCTensor.c.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Error: Build error: Failed building.
(tf0.12.1) [root@sd-bigdata-gpu-02 deepmask]#  lspci  | grep -i 'vga\|3d\|2d'
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200GL [Tesla M40] (rev a1)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200GL [Tesla M40] (rev a1)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 30)
83:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200GL [Tesla M40] (rev a1)
84:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200GL [Tesla M40] (rev a1)
```

I have install the cude 8.0 and cudnn . And I could also install other packages like nnx, optim, inn sucessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered this. The cause is due to a new method in the torch lib, see: https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/lib/TH/THStorage.c#L69

Update Torch by running `luarocks install torch` before `luarocks install cutorch` and you should be good to go.

Comment: thank，it works!  I thought I might have installed the torch7 for the newest version . And never notice it should be updated.

Comment: No problem. This would be easier if versions of dependencies were checked and auto-upgraded when necessary.